# How does armor work mathematically in QuakeLive?

Tags: quake-live

Armor is the most obvious point of contention in 1v1 Quake matches. How does it interact with health mathematically in preventing damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Armor absorbs 66% of the damage and 34% of it (the damage) will be removed from health. This formula will apply until all of your armor is absorbed and then all the damage will be directly hitting your HPs.

Sources :

1. Quake Live Wiki : http://quakelive.wikia.com/wiki/Armor
2. Personal Experience
3. Educated guess